# How do I find the sum of two categories for each year in this PostgreSQL dataset?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

Here's my dataset (in CSV form for easy reading):

```
item_category,year,price
"Bacon",1890,0.12
"Bacon",1891,0.126
"Bacon",1892,0.129
"Bacon",1893,0.142
"Eggs (dozen)",1890,0.208
"Eggs (dozen)",1891,0.221
"Eggs (dozen)",1892,0.221
"Eggs (dozen)",1893,0.224
```

I'd like to find the sum for the price of bacon and eggs for each year. So, the result I want would be:

```
item_category,year,price
"Bacon and eggs",1890,0.328
"Bacon and eggs",1891,0.347
"Bacon and eggs",1892,0.35
"Bacon and eggs",1893,0.366
```

I'm a novice at SQL, and I've been looking into Self-Join methods, but they don't seem to be exactly what I'm looking for -- I've basically run out of ideas for now.

If it helps, I also know how to use the Sequel gem for Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [`GROUP BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) and [aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html), not self-joins:

```
SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT item_category, ' and ' ORDER BY item_category)
                                                                   AS items
     , year
     , sum(price) AS price
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY year
ORDER  BY year
```

`string_agg(DISTINCT item_category, ' and ' ORDER BY item_category)` optionally concatenates distinct names to form the new label automatically. May work for you. Else replace it with your static label.

Answer (score 1):

```
select "Bacon and eggs", year, sum(price) 
from    table_name 
group by "Bacon and eggs", year
order by year;
```

Comment: Remove "Bacon and eggs" from `GROUP BY`. There is no need to group by a scalar value. Also, it would have to be single quotes `'Bacon and eggs'`, not double quotes, as this is a string value, not an identifier. IOW: this does not work at all.