# When getting sums in PostgreSQL, how do I skip over a row containing a null (or nil) value?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

My dataset:

```
item_category,year,price
"Bacon",1910,0.255
"Bacon",1911,0.247
"Bacon",1912,0.244
"Bacon",1913,0.27
"Bread",1913,0.056
"Bread",1914,0.063
"Bread",1915,0.07
"Bread",1916,0.073
```

My code so far:

```
SELECT
    string_agg(DISTINCT item_category, ' and ' ORDER BY item_category) AS items,
        year,
        sum(avg_yr_value) AS price
FROM
    earnings_and_prices
WHERE
    (item_category = 'Bacon' OR item_category = 'Bread')
GROUP BY
    year
ORDER BY
    year
```

My output (I use the Ruby gem sequel, so this is in Hash format):

```
{:items=>"Bacon", :year=>1910, :price=>0.255}
{:items=>"Bacon", :year=>1911, :price=>0.247}
{:items=>"Bacon", :year=>1912, :price=>0.244}
{:items=>"Bacon and Bread", :year=>1913, :price=>0.326}
{:items=>"Bacon and Bread", :year=>1914, :price=>0.338}
{:items=>"Bacon and Bread", :year=>1915, :price=>0.339}
{:items=>"Bacon and Bread", :year=>1916, :price=>1.017}
```

I only want the years which contain prices for both bacon and bread. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your query (after the `group by` but before the `order by`):

```
 having count(distinct item_category) = 2
```

That ensures that only groups that with two distinct item_categories will be included.

Comment: @user1626730: .. in which case the only possible result for `items` is `'Bacon and Bread'` again and you can replace `string_agg(...)` with this constant expression, like discussed under [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12645535/939860). It seems to have helped you spot this glitch, though. :)

Comment: Yep. Thanks, Erwin Brandstetter.